# Xcode libtool error on OpenTrack build

Tags: xcode, libtool-xcode

I have used CMake 3.3.0-rc4 to generate an Xcode project for OpenTrack.  However, when I attempt to build the ALL_BUILD target in Xcode 6.4, I immediately get the error below.

```
Libtool build/Debug/libopentrack-version.a normal x86_64
    cd /Users/david/Documents/Programming/OpenTrack
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/user/Documents/Programming/OpenTrack/build/Debug -filelist /Users/user/Documents/Programming/OpenTrack/build/opentrack.build/Debug/opentrack-version.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/opentrack-version.LinkFileList -stdlib=libc++ -framework Cocoa -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -lz -framework Carbon -o /Users/user/Documents/Programming/OpenTrack/build/Debug/libopentrack-version.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `t' in: -stdlib=libc++
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] [-no_warning_for_no_symbols]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

The Build Settings for the project has the following set for Linking / Other Librarian Flags:

```
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -framework Cocoa -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -lz -framework Carbon
```

From the libtool usage statement above, it looks to me like this set of options was generated for an entirely different version of libtool.  What can I do (if anything) to get this project to build with the current version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the flag `-stdlib=libc++` or `-framework` with `libtool`, as they are valid only in the linker, so you should make `OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS` empty as none of those options apply